# Nested Repeater - ItemCommand only fires if attached via markup

Tags: asp.net, events, repeater, webforms, databound-controls

I have a repeater nested in the `ItemTemplate` of a parent Repeater. I usually connect them to controls declaratively in markup.

```
<asp:Repeater runat='server' id='myParentRepeater'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat='server' id='mynestedRepeater' OnItemCommand='myMethod'>
           ...
        </asp:Repeater>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp>
```

Today I decided to do it in the code-behind, specifically in the `ItemDataBound` method of the parent repeater./

```
((Repeater)e.item.FindControl("MyParentRepeater")).ItemCommand += ...
```

But it won't work this way. Unless I use markup the event handler won't fire. Why is this? Or, assuming it *should* work, can someone tell me what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ItemDataBound` event is triggered only when the `Repeater` is databound and not on every postback. But events must be recreated on every postback. Hence use the [`ItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated.aspx) event instead.

```
protected void myParentRepeater_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
          ((Repeater)e.item.FindControl("MyParentRepeater")).ItemCommand += ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Does `ItemCreated` fire on every postback? Regardless of whether the control is rebound or not? I always assumed the wiring was done with javascript which would persist across postback ...

Comment: @5arx: Yes, `ItemCreated` is the event which is fired when the item (or row in case of a `GridView` and it's `RowCreated`-event) was (re)created. So that's where the controls are actually created.

Answer (score 1):

ADD

```
 OnItemCommand="repNested_ItemCommand"
```

to

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNested" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repSales_ItemCommand">
```

CodeBehind:

```
Protected Sub repNested_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs)


 Select Case e.CommandName
// Do whatever you want
```